# Hypothesis testing with exponential family

Tags: hypothesis-testing, distributions, gamma-distribution, exponential-family, convolution

I'm interested in running hypothesis tests for a variety of members of the exponential family with continuous support, for different values of the parameter/s, for a sample of n i.i.d random variables (distributed according to a particular member and parametrization of the exponential family).

In general, it seems the sufficient statistic (at least for a single parameter) is a sum of the variables in the sample.  I know this can be obtained at least theoretically from n-fold convolution, but in general, there does not seem to be a nice form for the distribution of this sum, which I will need to compute p-values.

so I'm wondering what distributions have known distributions for the sum of n i.i.d variables, and if there is a good reference for doing hypothesis testing with exponential family.

I know that:

- sums of iid exponentials are distributed Erlang
- sums of iid normals are distributed normal
- sums of iid gamma are distributed gamma (but what about product of gamma, which is the sufficient statistic for the shape parameter?)

So what about beta, pareto, log normal, and so on?

Is the difficulty of this the reason why no one does hypothesis tests anymore?

Comment: "*Is the difficulty of this the reason why no one does hypothesis tests anymore?*" -- your assertion is untrue, since lots of people do hypothesis tests, as even a casual perusal of the questions posed here on CV show (indeed, they're still used far more than they ought to be, I think). The reason isn't the difficulty of explicitly computing the algebraic distributional forms, since we can carry out tests without being able to do that.

Comment: right but it seems scientists and machine learning people are leaning more and more towards bayesian stats.  how can u carry out the tests without the distributions?  seems to me the bottleneck is mostly getting the p-values...

Comment: You're exactly right, the problem comes down to one of 'How do I find a p-value for this test if I can't compute the distribution of the test statistic explicitly?" -- one common solution is to use simulation, from which one may obtain simple probabilistic bounds on the p-value. Indeed computing power is such that a million simulations is often a matter of perhaps 20 seconds of typing\* and at worst a few additional seconds of waiting, and that pins the p-value down sufficiently narrowly for almost any practical purpose.  \*(at least with something well-suited to the task, such as R)